# rsync skipping directory and not transferring files

Tags: rsync

I am trying to move files from one directory to a server. This is the code I am using.

```
sudo rsync --remove-source-files --verbose --progress --include '*.plot' --exclude '*.tmp' /media/nvme500/ /media/tankv1/mining/chia/
```

The output is always "skipping directory" and the files do not get moved.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

You're missing either `-rt` (`--recursive` and `--times`) or `-a` (`--archive`). Without one of these two options you will only be able to copy files in the top-most source directory.

Since you're using `--remove-source-files` I would *strongly* recommend you test the resulting solution with `-n` (`--dry-run`):

```
sudo rsync --dry-run -avP --remove-source-files --exclude '*.tmp' /media/nvme500/ /media/tankv1/mining/chia/
```

You'll notice I've omitted `--include '*.plot`; this is because it's already included in the default set of all files to be transferred. If you wanted only to transfer `*.plot` files then that's a different requirement, where we exclude everything except these:

```
sudo rsync --dry-run -avP --remove-source-files --include '*.plot' --include '*/' --exclude '*' --prune-empty-dirs /media/nvme500/ /media/tankv1/mining/chia/
```

A final note: if you are copying to a FAT filesystem there are extra considerations to cope with its reduced functionality.